# Ошибка 404 при переходе на swagger-ui.html страницу

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

Я решил обновить версию Swagger и в итоге нарвался на проблему.

Имею зависимость:

```
 <!-- ==== Swagger ==== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Конфиг-бин:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;


@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Открываю URL `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` и получаю **404**. При этом сам свагер анализирует эндпоинты:

```
2019-01-06 21:20:52.921  INFO 29793 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
```

P.S: **Я проверял** [другие](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618350/swagger-with-spring-boot-2-0-leads-to-404-error-page) вопросы по этой проблеме и их решение мне никак не помогло.

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а какой полный путь к `html` в ресурсах проекта?

Comment: Стоп, так у Вас в логах явно замаплен путь /v2/api-docs, его же нудно использовать не?

Comment: @GenGloud а разве это имеет отношение к самому swagger-ui? Мне казалось - что нет

Comment: @Dima Khodan в ресурсах нету контекста приложения, поэтому к свагеру я стучусь через локалхост

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось.

Как оказалось, [зависимость](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2) **Swagger UI** просто не подгружалась maven'ом.

Дело в том, что IDE не использовала Maven, а генерила [mvnw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723833/what-is-the-purpose-of-mvnw-and-mvnw-cmd-files),  который уже и не подгружал нужную зависимость.

Но самое интересное, что mvnw wrapper подгружал swagger-ui версии версии до `2.6.1`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге, я выполнил следующее:

1. Удалил mvnw файл
2. выполнил `mvn clean install`
3. Перезагрузил IDE

И нужная зависимость подгрузилась:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По этой причине, если у Вас похожая проблема - просто попробуйте проверить, используется ли **Maven**.

Answer (score 1):

**Решение:**
Необходимо просто удалить @EnableWebMvc из классов конфигурации.

**Почему так:**
*@EnableWebMvc* включает класс *org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport*.
В spring-boot же есть класс автоконфигурации *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration*, у которого стоит аннотация *@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)*.

**Что в итоге получаем:** Добавляя в проект *@EnableWebMvc*, мы сами становимся ответственными за все, так как мы выключаем автоконфигурацию spring-bootа.

Comment: Зачем вы добавили ответ там, где это не нужно?

Comment: я описал в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить, поэтому написал

Comment: Не надо этого делать, если проблема уже давно найдена.

Comment: @SlandShow правилами не запрещено, следовательно - разрешено

Comment: @asianirish дело конечно ваше, но это очень странно.